# Oracle created in C or Java?

Tags: java, sql, c, oracle

So i've looked around online trying to figure out if Oracle(Database) was created in C/C++ or Java?
I've gotten answers saying either or, but not a definite answer?

seems like it should've been written in C, but then again im not sure. I even looked on their site and I can't find any information.

Thanks

Comment: The ORACLE codebase dates from the 1970s. Java dates from the 1990s. What do you think it's written in?

Comment: @Steve: Well, I *have* heard of Java being called "the new COBOL"...

Comment: @Gabe: I thought SQL was the new COBOL.

Comment: @Vadim: Actually, NoSQL is the new Java. I can see how you would be confused.

Comment: Nominated for re-opening as there are times when you actually need to relink Oracle, which isn't something you'd do with a Java implementation. So it isn't totally academic. http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/1264-Re-linking-oracle.html

Answer (score 10):

According to Tom Kyte:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:5228516811673

> Oracle was originally written in
>   fortran and then redone in C, which it
>   has been written  in ever since.  In
>   fact, when we ported Oracle to the
>   mainframe for the first time we  were
>   faced with an issue -- do we rewrite
>   Oracle in assembler (there was no c
>   compiler on  the mainframe back then)
>   or do we write a C compiler?  We wrote
>   a C compiler.

Answer (score 5):

The database engine itself is written in C (or C++)

See the entry for 1983 in the Oracle timeline:
http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/timeline/index.html

> *with server code written in the C programming language*

Comment: Presumably there is now a fair amount of Java in there too, since the JVM+libraries that run Java stored procedures are (I'd guess) written largely in Java. But that's not the core DB.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: you are right, there is a JVM integrated, but it's only there to run customer's code. I don't think that there is any Java code in the database engine itself. You can install Oracle without Java support, so the core definitely does not need it.

Comment: There are components that do rely on the Java in the database (eg bits of the media / image manipulation) but the core doesn't require it (and the the free XE version doesn't come with the JVM).

Answer (score 2):

Originally it was written in Assembly for the VAX/VMS. In 1982 Oracle V3 was written in C. [Here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) you will find a bit of Oracle history.

By the way, .. Larry Ellison hires the best professional skippers to race his sailing boat ... :-)

Comment: Oracle pre-dates the VAX - it was originally written in PDP-11 assembler.

Comment: It is true that Version 1 was developed on RSX-11, but transactions were developed on VAXen under VMS. After that they ported the system to Unix. On the other hand VMS was based on RSX-11M. Anyway, thank Dennis Richie for Unix...

Comment: I miss VMS - secure and reliable.